# Iterating over selenium webdriver's driver.find_elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have to scrape all the event details from the AXS.com website as a part on my webscraping assignment. I have tried using chrome web driver with Python+Selenium.

I am able to get the value by using `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` e.g. `driver.find_element_by_class_name("headliner").text`.

But this get only the first item. I got stuck by while I tried iterating after using `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='results-table results-table--events']")`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/.../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.axs.com/browse/music/alternative-punk")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
allevent_details = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='results-table results-table--events']")     
for i in allevent_details:
    print(i.find_element_by_class_name("headliner").text)
```

**Error**

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"headliner"}
(Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
```

Expected:

- Inner Wave
- BLOXX.... etc

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic as below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/.../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.axs.com/browse/music/alternative-punk")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
allevent_details = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='results-table results-table--events']//div[@class='headliner']")     
for i in allevent_details:
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of following locator.

### Using Xpath

```
allevent_details = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='results-table results-table--events']")
for i in allevent_details:
     print(i.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='headliner']").text)
```

### Using Css Selector

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.headliner'):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the *event headlines* from the [webpage](https://www.axs.com/browse/music/alternative-punk) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.headliner")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='headliner']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Inner Wave', 'BLOXX, Hembree and Warbly Jets', 'Frenship', 'LANY', 'together PANGEA & Vundabar', 'Night Beats', 'New Politics', 'The Technicolors', 'Davila 666', 'Vansire + BOYO', 'The Starting Line', 'Katzù Oso', 'The Raconteurs', 'Cayucas', 'ALT 98.7 Summer Camp']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```